# How to call functions declared out of a Vuejs instance?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

This is a pseudocode to illustrate my question. When the script is run, it will encounter the error func1 is not defined. How can I go about this?

app.js

```
require ('./helper');
new Vue ({
el: "#app",

created: function () {
func1()
}
});
```

helper.js

```
module.exports = function () {
  $.notify('Hi', {
    position: "bottom right",
    className: "success"
  });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to save the imported function to a variable in your app.js file. It depends on what bundler you use (e.g. browserify or webpack or else). Functions declared outside of the parameter object you are passing to Vue should be accessible:

```
// app.js
var func1 = require('./helper');
new Vue ({
    el: "#app",

    created: function () {
        func1();
    }
});
```

In your helpers.js, you need a reference to jQuery. You can either include the library (`jQuery` and `$` will be available globally on the `window` object) or like in the example below, install it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery and bundle it with your own code.

```
// helper.js
var $ = require('jquery');

module.exports = function () {
    $.notify('Hi', {
        position: "bottom right",
        className: "success"
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Using your example, I managed to get it to call the helper function. However, extending to my scenario, I'm using NotifyJS in the helper function. This again triggers the error $.notify is not a function

Comment: Could you the update your question with the content of helpers.js?

Comment: There you go. Thanks.

Comment: I came to realise that the notifyjs library that I npm was not the one I intended to use, therefore the function was not recognised. But, I'll take this as the answer to my earlier question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this function in more than one component's created method, you can create a mixin, which then will be passed to specific component.

```
//YourMixin.js
new Vue({
  created: function () { ... }
})

//Component
let mixin = require('YourMixin')

new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  ...
})
```